# Markdown equations not rendering correctly

Tags: markdown, jekyll, equation, mathjax

I have two equations (given below) written in Markdown with the latest version of Mathjax. (FYI: these are for a blog that I'm making using [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/).) When I place them in separate paragraphs, they render fine, but when they're in the same paragraph, they don't render correctly.

```
First equation is here \\(\mathbf{I}_n\\).

The next equation is here \\(D_j\\). More text.

First equation is here \\(\mathbf{I}_n\\). The next equation is here \\(D_j\\). More text.
```

[image]

The problem seems to be in the "I" being bold or in the subscript. When I remove the `\mathbf` surrounding "I" in the code where both equations are in the same paragraph, the code renders as expected:

[image]

When I remove the subscripts on "I" or "D", it also renders correctly:

[image]
[image]

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is an issue involving Markdown and Mathjax. Markdown interprets underscores as italicizing text while Mathjax wants to make them subscripts. According to these websites ([1](https://pennbay.github.io/tech/mathjax.with.hugo/) and [2](https://gohugo.io/content-management/formats/#mathjax-with-hugo)), Markdown gets to the underscores first and converts them into HTML `<i> <\i>` tags. Then, Mathjax is unable to process the underscores correctly.

A [hack](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/329) to solving this is escaping the underscores with a backslash:

```
First equation is here \\(\mathbf{I}\_n\\). The next equation is here \\(D\_j\\). More text.
```

[image]

but this only works for `inlineMath` equations (those delimited by `\\( \\)`) and not `displayMath` equations (those delimited by `\\[ \\]`). Thus, the solution is:

1. If using an inline equation, replace `_` by `\_`.
2. If using a display equation, don't change anything.